# mixed logit (mlogit) with socio-demographic variables

Tags: logistic-regression, mixed, discrete

I conducted discrete choice experiment but have been analyzed for 2 months. Anybody helps me with this mixed logit problem...

My experiment was conducted with **3 alternatives (option 1, option 2, option 3) and 3 attributes (soc, man, inc)**

I also have a few **individual characteristics** and want to use these:

avg.charge.cost, avg.charge.num, milage start.time.mon,

start.time.aft, start.time.eve, start.time.nig, start.time.rand
(these are dummy variables)

It is hard to interpret with socio-demographic variables. Below is the mlogit code and results.
I cannot interpret socio-demographic variables such as "start.time.mon:2" **since 2 is just the name of option which is consist of 3 alternatives (soc, man, inc)**. It is not like boat, charter, something like in example......

Therefore, it doesn't have meaning such as start.time.mon:2, start.time.eve:3,milage:2  ...

1. How can I delete intercept:2, intercept:3? and
2. How should I put individual characteristics in this situation?

```
Code:

    Call:
mlogit(formula = choice ~ soc + man + inc | avg.charge.cost + 
    avg.charge.num + milage + start.time.mon + start.time.aft + 
    start.time.eve + start.time.nig | 0, data = dce.mlogit.alt3, 
    rpar = c(soc = "n", man = "n", inc = "n"), R = 100, halton = NA, 
    panel = TRUE)

Result:

[enter image description here][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx5rF.png
```

Comment: (result is in the image)

Comment: - In this case, how can I interpret with these results? I want to investigate how each individual characteristic term affect my attribute, which is soc, man, inc.